# C# Using a Json WebService in production

Tags: c#, .net, json

How should one write a library that is responsible for connecting to a restful api? The lib should provide methods for direct access for the api functions. Is using **`WebClient`** to get the response as string and **`Json.NET`** to deserialize them as objects a reliable, acceptable way of doing this?

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true;//the server uses a self signed SSL cert

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("..", "....");
    string str = client.DownloadString("https://..../users/"+UserId+"/super-secret-data");     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a class for each group of calls (user management, up/downloading data,...). this class implements some functions (mapping the web calls). so when you want to list all new member, then you can write

```
var accounting = new Accounting();
var memberList = accounting.GetNewMember();
```

This function ( GetNewMember() ) is simply a wrapper. In the function you call the REST-full API get the JSON back an convert it into the result you want.

And for creating the URIs, you can use the **string.Format(string, object[])** overloading.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, or you can use code generation with visual studio and swagger to import a rest web api in your solution.

Comment: Thanks, I already use swagger, I did not know that I can use it for auto import! Sorry thing that I already wrote the whole Api connector. :D